# unable to start program Project\Debug\Test.exe wasn't found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Visual Studio and I really don't have any idea of how it works.

I tried to make a simple "Hello World!" to print in C++, and started debugging.
But then I got the following message:
"Unable to start program
'c:\Users\name\source\repos\Project\Debug\Test.exe'
The file was not found."
I saw someone on a different post who was told to press "Set as StartUp Project" at the name of the project.
Other than that, I don't really know where to look for the answer. I've searched around the net, but couldn't find anything.
I hope you can help.

Comment: Have you created a `C++` project?

Comment: I made an empty file with the following code
`#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main(){ 
 cout << "Hello World";  
return 0;  
}`

Comment: Go to menu project create new C++ project (console) then compile and build & run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your project first, then start debugging.
If you don't you get this message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing likely is caused because you did not **build the program**. Try building the program by going to the **Build menu** (Located to the right of Project and to the left of Debug), then press **build solution** in the dropdown list that appears. Wait until it is finished building, and you will likely have a working program again when you start debugging. If this does not work, you may have a bug with visual studio, in which case you must restart. If none of the above works for you, your best solution would be creating a new program and pasting the code from the old program into the new one.